# Refreshing iOS IAP receipt to restore purchases always return a receipt even if no purchase has been made

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm implementing a Restore button in my app so that the user can restore IAP on his device (auto-renewal subscription). The code is very simple (iOS 7+):

```
request = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] init];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
```

When I run this code, the App Store prompts for user credentials, but I get a valid receipt even though the App Store user hasn't purchased anything.

How can I differentiate between the case where the user has a valid subscription linked to their iTunes account and the case where the user doesn't have a valid subscription to restore? Or is it unnecessary to implement this logic in the Restore button?

Thanks,

Comment: [When to refresh a receipt vs restore purchases in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52162283/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7 and later (and in OS X v10.9 and later, IIRC), the operating system provides a receipt for the app itself.  So you're guaranteed a minimal receipt once you refresh it, even if you have no purchases.